# PL SQL to read blob field

Tags: sql, oracle, blob

I am trying to retrieve data from a blob field but i get the error message

> **ORA-06502:** PLSQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long ORA-6512: at Line 1.

This is my script:-

```
SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(a.TXD_DOC, 4000,1)) 
  FROM vwe_txt_documents a
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help please? All I want is to read normal text from a blob field.

Comment: You need to show us your complete procedure, not just an incomplete part of it

Comment: you must try to fetch the first 2000 characters and let us know the result.

Comment: upper limit the value 4000 conforms to CLOB, but for BLOB try a less value such as 2000 as @Tejash already told.

Comment: with 2000 it brings back but the output is not normal text its like this: - xÚ•VÛnG}Ž

Comment: If it is a blob, chances are it contains binary data, and not text. This explains why you get that kind of output. The 2K chars and not 4k are probably due to characterset conversion.

Comment: what would be the best way to read the binary data?